# Find Source File using Pivot table in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I have a sheet with Pivot Table.
How do I find the source file?

If I double click on A Row, I get source file of that particular data.
But I require the Base Source File.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

1. Select a cell in your Pivot Table.
2. Go to `Options > Change Data Source > Connection Properties`
3. Choose the `Definition Tab` and you'll see where the Pivot Table is drawing data from.